# Is it possible to insert an image into an automata node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I am building a little automaton and since one state is basically representing a sine wave I wondered if it's possible to have a little sine wave pdfplot or something inside the note instead of just writing "Sine wave" or something like that.

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state,initial] (Neutral)                    {$Neutral$};
\node[state]         (Sine)    [right=of Neutral] {$Sine$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And `\includegraphics[width= 0.3\textwidth]{testimage}` instead of Sine won't work obviously. So is there any other way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\includegraphics` in a node works perfectly fine. Another option is to plot a sine wave in a `path picture`.

Unrelated: "Neutral" and "Sine" are words, not mathematical expressions, don't write them in math mode. Use `\textit{Neutral}` if you want italics.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state,initial] (Neutral)      {Neutral};
\node[state,right=of Neutral] (Sine) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}};
\node[state,
      right=of Sine,
      minimum size=2cm,
      path picture={
        \draw plot[domain=-pi:pi] ({\x/(2*pi)},{sin(\x*180/pi)/2}); 
      } ] (Sine2) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm an idiot, I think I put the includegraphics command in the wrong parentheses... Thank you! Besides, I think your sine wave looks even better than mine :) Also yes, I know they are no mathematical expressions, I was just playing around and wondering what it looks like in math mode, so basically leftovers.